# Android-x86 on virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, android

I installed Android-x86 on Virtual Box, but when I try to enable wifi, I'm getting error.

"unable to scan networks"

Do you have any solution for this issue?

I have **intel(R) wireless wifi link 4965agn** card

Comment: For those voting it as off topic; android X86 is a desktop operating system, it's valid here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most vm software don't expose the full range of physical hardware to your VM, as Eli says, and in the case of wireless networking you have a 'bridged' connection, which in effect emulates an ethernet connection between your host and guest. One workaround that i found is, rather than using the built in (mini pci-e) based wireless, is to use a usb based wireless device, which can be passed through to the VM.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox presents an Ethernet interface to it's VM's, not WiFi. With Android-x86 there should be an "Ethernet" menu in the settings. It will just share your computer's internet connection, not interfering with it.

Comment: you say that the problem is about VM, so if I install Android-x86 not on vm, as a second os, can I run wifi?